# How to add block inside block in YII nordcms

Tags: content-management-system, yii, yii-extensions

I have used Crisu83-nordcms for CMS purpose
as this CMS provide adding block to page using `{{block:blockname}}`
and it works
but i want to add block inside block using

```
{{block:blockname1}}

{{block:blockname2}}

{{block:blockname3}} ......
```

in CMS block Available tags does nit contain `{{block:name}}` ...how can i add that.
so that block can contain other block using `{{block:name}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NordCms doesn't allow for using blocks inside blocks to avoid the need to check for possible recursion. We left out that feature in order to keep things simple. Feel free to fork the project and do the necessary modifications yourself if you wish.